# All wordpress posts of a specific category will display in page.php

Tags: wordpress

I am creating an wordpress theme.I have added all the categories dynamically into the Top menu.Now i want all the posts under the category when i click on any menu item.But code is getting all the posts of all categories.Here is my code.

```
<?php 
                global $wp_query;
                $id = $wp_query->post->ID;
                $the_query = new WP_Query( $id );
                $count = 0;
                // The Loop
                if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
                $the_query->the_post();?>
                <div class="page-header"><h3><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h3></div>
                <?php
                $count++;
                }
                } else {?>
                no posts found
                <?php }
                /* Restore original Post Data */
                wp_reset_postdata();
                ?>
```

How can i solve the problem.

Comment: If you echo out $id what is printed out?

Comment: Then the category id is printed ok.I have tested it.But when i want to print all the posts under that category, then all the posts of all categories prints.how can i solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php 
            global $wp_query;
            $id = $wp_query->post->ID;
            $the_query = new WP_Query( $id );
            $count = 0;
            // The Loop
    query_posts('cat=22'); #enter your category id here
            if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) {
            while ($the_query->have_posts()) : the_post();
            $the_query->the_post();?>
            <div class="page-header"><h3><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a></h3>    
            </div>
            <?php
            $count++;
    endwhile; 
            } 
    else 
    {
    ?>
            no posts found
            <?php 
    }
            /* Restore original Post Data */
            wp_reset_postdata();
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$the_query = new WP_Query('cat='.$id );
```

Comment: I have tried it but now when i click one of the menu all the categories are showing "Now Rows Found".

Comment: clicked post must contain one category .. did you check it ??

Comment: can you give me you online website link which have a problem ??